# How to import ex.js file to ex.component.ts?

Tags: javascript, typescript, console, angular6

```
 import { jsFile } from '../about/ex1.js';
 constructor() {
  jsFile(); // Method
  }
```

[jsFile position img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg2k1.png)

I have error in console 
[error console img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLrLt.png)

Comment: This is just a guess, but I think you haven't exported the function in the ex1.js file. Is it okay to show what the `jsFile` function looks like?

Comment: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AboutComponent -> javaScript]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AboutComponent -> javaScript]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for javaScript!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AboutComponent -> javaScript]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AboutComponent -> javaScript]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for javaScript!

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused as to what you're doing now. Could I see the `jsFile` function in the ex1.js file and the constructor of your AboutComponent?

Comment: yes, I wanna to get data of javascript to typescript

Comment: Have you done this? ```export function jsFile() { // ... }```?

Comment: yes, I am done .

Comment: yes , it's works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 -- In ex1.js --
 export function isFile() {
   // Code
 }

 -- In AboutComponent --
 import { jsFile } from '../about/ex1.js';

 constructor() {
   jsFile(); // Method
 }
```

Try exporting `isFile`.

Comment: Can you tell me how to export ex1.js of assets

Comment: Data in your assets folder? You should use http client to make a request to get that.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood. I don't really know what you want to do here.

Comment: hahahahahah, I wanna get data of src/assets/data/ex.json use src/app/about/ex.js :D

Comment: Oh, you used `js` instead of `json`?

Comment: I see! :D Sorry for not understanding you the first time.